# remove non-selected keys from array of objects or create new array of objects with only selected value

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have this array to help me with my input select options

Input select:

```
<select id="example-select"></select>
```

And the array with the options

```
const array_axis = ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'];//these are the options of my input select
```

This is how I use that array as options for my input select:

```
var select = document.getElementById("example-select");
for (index in array_axis) {
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(array_axis[index], array_axis[index]);
}
```

This is the array I want to work with using the input select

```
const data = [{
  agrupacion: 'Hombre',
  col2015: 26.4,
  col2016: 28.7,
  col2017: 25.7,
  col2018: 23.7,
  col2019: 22.7,
  col2020: 26.4
}, {
  agrupacion: "Mujer",
  col2015: 26.8,
  col2016: 29,
  col2017: 27.1,
  col2018: 24.7,
  col2019: 24.4,
  col2020: 27.3
}];
```

What I need is to be able to select an option(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020) and remove all the other keys that don't match in my data array.

For example if I pick 2017 that matches the key "col2017" so remove every other key that was not selected and leave the array like this

```
const data = [{
  agrupacion: 'Hombre',
  name: 25.7
}, {
  agrupacion: "Mujer",
  name: 27.1
}];
```

or rather than removing everything that wasn't selected, I figured it would probably be easier to create a new array with the selected keys instead and this is what I've tried so far:

```
$("#example-select").change(function(){
  var selection = 'col'+this.value;
  const selected = data.map(e => ({
    name: e.agrupacion,
    data: selection
  }));
  console.log(selected);
  
});
```

but my output is this:

```
[{
  data: "col2017",
  name: "Hombre"
}, {
  data: "col2017",
  name: "Mujer"
}];
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#example-select").change(function(){
  var selection = 'col'+this.value;
  const selected = data.map(e => ({
    agrupacion: e.agrupacion,
    name: e[selection]
  }));
  console.log(selected);
});
```

Basically instead of using `name: selection` use `name: e[selection]`